# how to resize a image being printed over another image (swift3)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, scale, cgrect

Right now my code saves a blue box over a red box. I need to shrink the size of the blue box by 50 percent. So that there is a red border around all of the blue box. I have a extension file that should be able to shrink the image but I don't know where to put it into my code.

[image: Pic]

```
 extension UIImage {
func resized(withPercentage percentage: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
    let canvasSize = CGSize(width: size.width * percentage, height: size.height * percentage)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(canvasSize, false, scale)
    defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
    draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: canvasSize))
    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
}
func resized(toWidth width: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
    let canvasSize = CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat(ceil(width/size.width * size.height)))
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(canvasSize, false, scale)
    defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
    draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: canvasSize))
    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
}}

import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var image1 = UIImage(named: "red")
var image2 = UIImage(named: "blue")




    func cropImageIntoQuarterSquare(image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
        let originalImageSize: CGSize = image.size
        let smallImageSize = CGSize(width: (originalImageSize.width + 40), height: (originalImageSize.height + 40))


        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(smallImageSize)
        image.draw(at: CGPoint.zero)
        let imageResult = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return imageResult
    }



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()}
    func saveImage(image1: UIImage, image2: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
        let size1 = image1.size
        let size2 = image2.size
        let origin = CGPoint(x: size1.width - size2.width, y: size1.height - size2.height)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size1)
        image1.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size1))
        image2.draw(in: CGRect(origin: origin, size: size2))
        let combinedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return combinedImage
    }

    func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
        if let error = error {
            // we got back an error!
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Save error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
            present(ac, animated: true)
        } else {
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Saved!", message: "Your altered image has been saved to your photos.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
            present(ac, animated: true)
        }
    }



@IBAction func d(_ sender: Any) {


    guard let croppedImage = cropImageIntoQuarterSquare(image: image2!),
        let combinedImage = saveImage(image1: image1!, image2: croppedImage) else {
            // handle the error
            return
    }

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(combinedImage, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
    }}
```

Comment: my answer didnt solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function might help you. You can edit the size and origin values as per your wish

```
func drawImage() -> UIImage {
    var bottomImage = UIImage(named: "red")
    //background image
    let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "blue")
    //foreground image
    let newSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize)

    bottomImage.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height))

    image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 40, height: 40), blendMode: .normal, alpha: 1.0)
    let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
  }
```

Comment: replace the red with bottomImage and blue with fgImage

Comment: what is fgimage? I want a red border around the blue image.

Comment: are you using storyboards?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137105/discussion-between-ganesh-kumar-and-jason-stone).

Comment: no the only thing on the storyboard is the button to save the photo